# What is the difference between an LED and a lamp?

Tags: led

What is the difference between an LED and a lamp? If they are different, how can I tell if a component is a LED or a lamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lamp, unlike a LED, will eventually get very hot. A LED requires less voltage than a lamp. However, LEDs are quite expensive. Fortunately, LEDs are getting cheaper over time. LEDs can also be shrunk way more than you can shrink a lamp.

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

there are a lot different Lamps, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamp for "Lamp (electrical component)
LED may be used as for "LED Lamps" or for the electronic part.
=> A lamp may contain a LED.
A Lamp can be light bulb, vacuumed, with a special wire, glowing if voltage attached to the light bulb. A lamp usually has a socket - and a defined operating voltage.

To recognize it as LED Lamp:

1. Look - a LED lamp needs a electronic circuit to work. it is usually inside the socket, older ones have a white part between the socket and the glass, newer ones look like older light bulbs, but the "glowing wire" is a yellow or orange led wire - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LED_lamp for examples.
2. Efficiency - Wattage written on the bulb - A LED Lamp usually has a low wattage for a high Light emission e.g. 6 watts for 500lm instead of 60 watts light bulbs
3. Heat emission - LED will not heat your hand if you are near as 2 to 10 inches (one reason for their efficiency).

If the wattage is not printed, you may use a energy monitor (a device as wall plug providing a socket and a display) but the heat dissipation will be much more with a glowing light bulb as with a LED.
Note: A LED also emits heat but usually not hot enough to boil a drop of water.